# Scp the data which is only of 1 day

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp, scp

I want to scp the directory and its contents located in /backup folder which will be only 1 day old. I am using the below command which brings all the directories and files from remote to local host which is older than 1 day but i want only folder and its content for 1 day old only.

Command use to scp from remote to local.

```
sshpass -p "password" scp -rv find "/backup" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime -1 oracle@192.168.252.38:/backup/ /bkp
```

The file present is of Jul which should not be picked from the above command instead it should fail.
The thing which i want is if today is 30-Aug-2018 but i want only the data to be scp is 29-Aug-2018.

Files under /back folder:

```
[oracle@ back]$ ls -lrt
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle dba 12288 Jul 23 18:32 2018-07-23
```

Comment: try `rsync`. Example here: https://www.nicovs.be/rsync-files-younger-or-older-than/

Comment: In your `scp` command you are transferring from `/backup`, but your `ls` is on `/back`. Are they the same folder?

Comment: @rahoogan : Its the  same folder i.e. /back . Sorry for the typing error